# AccessDataSourcce update with where condition

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

Trying to update an access database in asp using visual studio.

```
Dim accessDatabase2 As New AccessDataSource
accessDatabase2 = New AccessDataSource("Prestiege.accdb", "SELECT * FROM Rooms ;")
accessDatabase2.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Rooms] SET [Occupancy] = 1 Where [RoomType] = Single ;"
accessDatabase2.Update()
```

If I **remove** the **where condition** it works fine. I get this error otherwise:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more   required parameters.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with single quotes when giving string parameter

```
accessDatabase2.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [Rooms] SET [Occupancy] = 1 Where [RoomType] = 'Single';"
```